# How to create link in HTML page that point to class in frame

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I have an html page and in it I have a frame (or iframe in HTML5).
Is there a way to create a link that point to specific class / ID / link that in the frame?

Answer (score 1):

if you do not use cross domains you can reach your iframe with javascript with below code

```
frame=document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document;
link=frame.getElementById('mylink').href;
```

Comment: but in the HTML- do you know if there is a way to do that?

Comment: i m not sure but i think not